# Read multiple files from multiline textbox

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

Here i have developed a simple tool which reads a xml file and remove the nodes which doesn't have the Prices in it. Now it reads a single XML file.

But i need to read multiple XML file and parse all the files at the same time. Can someone help me in doing the same.

```
private void LoadNewFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog XmlFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    XmlFile.Title = "Browse XML File";
    string FilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    XmlFile.InitialDirectory = FilePath;
    XmlFile.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = XmlFile.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        OldFilePath = XmlFile.FileName;
    }
}

private void RemovePrice()
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNodeList emptyElements;
    xmldoc.Load(NewFilePath);
    emptyElements = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("book");
    for (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string price= emptyElements[i]["price"].InnerText;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(price))
            emptyElements[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(emptyElements[i]);
    }
    xmldoc.Save(OldFilePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To load ultiple files use `Multiselect` property and set it to `true`. Parallel processing can be done by use of `Parallel.ForEach` loop. And then you just slightly rewrite your main method to operate in this framework. Below sample code (not tested though):

```
    private void ProcessFiles()
    {
        // This property should be set somewhere in the c-tor.
        // It's here just for presentation purposes.
        this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the files 
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(
                this.openFileDialog1.FileNames,
                file =>
                    {
                        string oldFilePath = file;
                        string newFilePath = "Processed" + file;
                    });
        }
    }

    private void RemovePrice(string oldFilePath, string newFilePath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList emptyElements;
        xmldoc.Load(newFilePath);
        emptyElements = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("book");
        for (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string price = emptyElements[i]["price"].InnerText;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(price))
                emptyElements[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(emptyElements[i]);
        }
        xmldoc.Save(oldFilePath);
    }
```

Comment: Might want to note that `Parallel` is in `System.Threading.Tasks`. Just to preempt that question from others.

Comment: @JClaspill Make sense. I've actually added the whole path instead of a using statement.